# How do I send clean YouTube link?

Tags: youtube, sharing

I am new on YouTube. When I send a link to the receiver not only sees my video but also sees a series of unwanted news items. How do I send a clean link?

Answer (score 1):

by "unwanted news items" you mean after playback ends?

`rel=0` is what you seek (probably)

for more intel >> https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playlist

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/101892)

Comment: @serenesat: I think this answers the question just fine, in at least as much as it can be answered. The problem is a little muddy.

Comment: Perhaps this helps - I sent a link to someone which they received along with links to news stories and other video content  - i just want to be able to send a clean link with no ride along - My videos are on health issues and i am getting attached links to other such as breaking news etc

Comment: @ale: After edit it looks fine.

Comment: @Dennis: That's important information that should be in your question. Comments are meant to be temporary.